# NoMethodError: undefined method `ActiveSupport' in rails test file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded ruby & rails today (2.2.0, 4.2.1).

In `app/test/models/user_test.rb'

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport:TestCase
    test 'the truth' do
      assert false
    end
end
```

I ran rake `db:test:prepare`  then `rake test`.

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `ActiveSupport' for main:Object
/Users/quantum/sonar/app/test/models/user_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Brand new Rails project. What am I missing?

```
app/test/testhelper:

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Comment: can you show `test_helper`?

Comment: Yes, I added in. This is a brand new rails project & I'm following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command. Hope it helps.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```